# Parsing and converting DMS Coordinates from String to Double

Tags: swift, unit-conversion

I have some coordinates looking like

> N47° 15' 36.75",E011° 20' 38.28",+001906.00

and I've created a class to parse and convert them to `Double`:

```
struct PLNWaypointCoordinate {
    var latitude: Double = 0.0
    var longitude: Double = 0.0

    init(coordinateString: String) {
        self.latitude = convertCoordinate(string: coordinateString.components(separatedBy: ",")[0])
        self.longitude = convertCoordinate(string: coordinateString.components(separatedBy: ",")[1])
    }

    private func convertCoordinate(string: String) -> Double {
        var separatedCoordinate = string.characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)

        let direction = separatedCoordinate[0].components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.letters.inverted).first
        let degrees = Double(separatedCoordinate[0].components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)[1])
        let minutes = Double(separatedCoordinate[1].components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)[0])
        let seconds = Double(separatedCoordinate[2].components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)[0])

        return convert(degrees: degrees!, minutes: minutes!, seconds: seconds!, direction: direction!)
}

    private func convert(degrees: Double, minutes: Double, seconds: Double, direction: String) -> Double {
        let sign = (direction == "W" || direction == "S") ? -1.0 : 1.0
        return (degrees + (minutes + seconds/60.0)/60.0) * sign
    }

}
```

Is there a better and safer way to perform this conversion?

Last method I've picked up here. Sorry, but I can't find the link to reference it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined a *value type* (`struct`) and not a `class`, which is good. In

```
var latitude: Double = 0.0
var longitude: Double = 0.0
```

you can omit the type annotations because the compiler can infer the
type automatically:

```
var latitude = 0.0
var longitude = 0.0
```

But actually I would go the other way around and replace the initial
values by an `init()` method. The reason is that – since you defined
your own init method – there is no default memberwise initializer anymore.
Therefore I would start with

```
struct PLNWaypointCoordinate {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double

    init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }

    // ...
}
```

which allows you to create a value not only from a string, but
also from a given latitude and longitude:

```
let c = PLNWaypointCoordinate(latitude: ..., longitude: ...)
```

Your `init(coordinateString: String)` method *assumes* that the given
string is in a valid format and can crash otherwise (by accesssing
out-of-bounds array elements or unwrapping `nil`s). As
@Ashley already said in his answer, you should define a 
*failable* initializer instead, which returns `nil` if the input is
invalid:

```
init?(coordinateString: String) { ... }
```

Alternatively, define a `throw`ing initializer:

```
init(coordinateString: String) throws { ... }
```

which throws an error for invalid input.

Your helper methods `convertCoordinate` and `convert` are *private,*
which is good. They do not use any properties of the value, which means
that they can be made `static`.

The conversion helper function is *very lenient,* it will for example
accept `X47 15 36.75` instead of `N47° 15' 36.75"` 
as latitude. It does not check that the coordinate starts with
a valid direction, or that the proper separators are used.

I don't know what the final part `+001906.00` stands for, but that
is ignored completely in your code.

There is also a flaw in your conversion, the fractional part
of the seconds is ignored, e.g. `36.75"` is taken as `36` seconds.

I would suggest to use `Scanner` instead, which makes it relatively
easy to check for a valid input and simultaneously
parse the values into variables. To distinguish
 between latitude and longitude, two arguments for the positive
and the negative direction are passed to the helper method.

The complete code then looks like this:

```
struct PLNWaypointCoordinate {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double

    init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }

    init?(coordinateString: String) {
        let components = coordinateString.components(separatedBy: ",")
        guard components.count >= 2,
            let latitude = PLNWaypointCoordinate.convertCoordinate(coordinate: components[0],
                                                                   positiveDirection: "N",
                                                                   negativeDirection: "S"),
            let longitude = PLNWaypointCoordinate.convertCoordinate(coordinate: components[1],
                                                                    positiveDirection: "E",
                                                                    negativeDirection: "W")
            else {
                return nil
        }
        self.init(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }

    private static func convertCoordinate(coordinate: String,
                                          positiveDirection: String,
                                          negativeDirection: String) -> Double? {
        // Determine the sign from the first character:
        let sign: Double
        let scanner = Scanner(string: coordinate)
        if scanner.scanString(positiveDirection, into: nil) {
            sign = 1.0
        } else if scanner.scanString(negativeDirection, into: nil) {
            sign = -1.0
        } else {
            return nil
        }

        // Parse degrees, minutes, seconds:
        var degrees = 0
        var minutes = 0
        var seconds = 0.0
        guard scanner.scanInt(&degrees),         // Degrees (integer),
            scanner.scanString("°", into: nil),  // followed by °,
            scanner.scanInt(&minutes),           // minutes (integer)
            scanner.scanString("'", into: nil),  // followed by '
            scanner.scanDouble(&seconds),        // seconds (floating point),
            scanner.scanString("\"", into: nil), // followed by ",
            scanner.isAtEnd                      // and nothing else.
            else { return nil }

        return sign * (Double(degrees) + Double(minutes)/60.0 + seconds/3600.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Scanner is exactly the way to handle this - great answer

Comment: @AshleyMills: Thank you! – But you covered the most imported point already (making the initialization failable).

Answer (score 2):

You should certainly be removing any force unwraps - which in turn means you'll need to use more optional values…

First thoughts

```
struct PLNWaypointCoordinate: CustomStringConvertible {
    var latitude: Double = 0.0
    var longitude: Double = 0.0

    init?(coordinateString: String) {
        let components = coordinateString.components(separatedBy: ",")
        guard components.count >= 2,
            let latitude = convertCoordinate(string: components[0]),
            let longitude = convertCoordinate(string: components[1])  else {
                return nil
        }

        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }

    var description: String {
        return "(\(latitude),\(longitude))"
    }

    private enum Direction: String {
        case N, E, S, W
        var sign: Double { return self == .S || self == .W ? -1 : 1 }
    }
    private func convertCoordinate(string: String) -> Double? {
        let separatedCoordinate = string.characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)

        let nonAlphas = CharacterSet.letters.inverted
        let nonDecimals = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
        guard let directionString = separatedCoordinate[0].components(separatedBy: nonAlphas).first,
            let direction = Direction(rawValue: directionString),
            let degrees = Double(separatedCoordinate[0].components(separatedBy: nonDecimals)[1]),
            let minutes = Double(separatedCoordinate[1].components(separatedBy: nonDecimals)[0]),
            let seconds = Double(separatedCoordinate[2].components(separatedBy: nonDecimals)[0]) else {
                return nil
        }

        return convert(degrees: degrees, minutes: minutes, seconds: seconds, direction: direction)
    }

    private func convert(degrees: Double, minutes: Double, seconds: Double, direction: Direction) -> Double {
        return (degrees + (minutes + seconds/60)/60) * direction.sign
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was planning on cleaning up the force unwraps as what I posted it was just a prototype, but I didn't want to start the cleanup until I got some more input.